# How can I make a slow loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops

I've made a GUI in Java and I looked up how to slow down a loop. All of the methods online don't work and the GUI freezes upon triggering the loop, this happens also without the line(s) to slow down the loop too. Here's my code (with the main bits, and variables changed to a *coin* system):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    static int coins = 0;
    static int autoCoinsLevel = 0;
    int autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost = 100;
    String versionRing = "Alpha";
    String versionNumber = "1.2";
    JLabel coinText;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel autoCoinsCostText;
    
    public GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        JButton autoClickUpgradeButton = new JButton("Auto Generator - Level " + autoCoinsLevel);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        autoCoinsUpgradeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(coins >= autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost && autoCoinsLevel < 9) {
                    autoCoinsLevel++;
                    autoCoinsUpgradeButton.setText("Auto Coin Maker - Level " + autoClickLevel);
                    coins = coins - autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost;
                    coinText.setText("Coins: " + coins);
                    autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost = autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost * 10;
                    autoCoinsCostText.setText("Auto Coin Maker Upgrade Cost: " + autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost + " Coins");
                    frame.pack();
                    while(autoCoinsLevel > 0) {
                        if(autoCoinsLevel == 1) {
                            coins++;
                            // delay 1 seconds
                        } else if(autoCoinsLevel == 2) {
                            coins++;
                            // delay .75 seconds
                        }
                        // and so on until `autoCoinsLevel == 9`
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        coinText = new JLabel("Coins: 0");
        autoCoinsCostText = new JLabel("Auto Coin Maker Upgrade Cost: " + autoCoinsNextLevelUpgradeCost + " Coins");
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(60, 100, 30, 100));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(coinsText);
        panel.add(autoCoinsUpgradeButton);
        panel.add(autoCoinsCostText);
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Clicker Clicker - " + versionRing + " " + versionNumber);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // increase coins script
    }
}
```

I don't know *why* the application stops responding with most methods I try, and nothing to slow it down at all also makes the application hang...

I am *very* new to Java so an explanation on what *this* or *that* does would help me understand better. :)

Comment: You never want to slow down the swing main thread. This is what controls your gui. You want to use a timer thread to do the timings while letting the swing thread handle the rest of the gui.

Comment: The app is backed by a single thread, if it is busy looping, it can't handle other things...to **delay** operations you don't have to block the thread, but postpone the operation, look at the class `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: @rascio *"..look at the class `java.util.Timer`"* Since all Swing/AWT apps should be created and updated on the Event Dispatch Thread, it's easier to use a `javax.swing.Timer` which ensures actions within are performed on the EDT.

Comment: Ah, sorry I never used swing :D I didn't knew about its specific class. Then yep it is the right one, no concurrency issue with it.

Comment: Your autoCoinsLevel is being updated in the EDT but that update is probably not being seen in the main thread (possibly due to hosting of the while loop).  The variable should be declared `volatile`. I provided a demo of this behavior in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

As @NomadMaker pointed out , better to make a separate thread since the main thread controls the GUI.

I would create a WaitThread class as follows

```
public class WaitThread extends Thread{
    private long waitInMs;

    public WaitThread(long waitInMs){
        this.waitInMs = waitInMs;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for "+this.waitInMs+" ms");
            sleep(this.waitInMs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then from main thread as follows

```
// Note: Looks like this is a forever running while loop 
while(autoCoinsLevel > 0) {
        
        if(autoCoinsLevel == 1) {
           coins++;
           // delay 1 seconds
           WaitThread waitThread = new WaitThread(1*1000);
           waitThread.start();
           waitThread.join();
        } else if(autoCoinsLevel == 2) {
           coins++;
           // delay .75 seconds
           WaitThread waitThread = new WaitThread((long)0.75*1000);
           waitThread.start();
           waitThread.join();
        }
        // and so on until `autoCoinsLevel == 9`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's very easy to understand which helps a lot (I'm very inexperienced and don't know much at all about Java).
Doing this prints out the `Waiting for 1000 ms` line but the GUI becomes unresponsive. Anyway to keep it responsive once it's been triggered?

Comment: After adding a line like this [`System.out.println("\"Coins\" is currently at " + coins)`] to the code, the console says that the `coins` variable is increasing, at 1 per second; which is exactly what I wanted. But still, **the GUI _won't_ respond**.

Answer (score 0):

You're variable `autoCoinslevel` and possibly others are being updated in the EDT.  The main thread has no clue about this and thus is not seeing the latest update of these values.  Check out the difference the `volatile` keyword makes below.

- First run the program as is. Clicking the button increments autoCoinsLevel but does not change the loop behavior as one might expect - printing when the count is odd but stopping when it is even.
- Then change `int autoCoinsLevel = 0` to `volatile int autoCoinsLevel = 0` and see the difference.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class VolatileDemo extends JPanel {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    
    int autoCoinsLevel = 0;
    
    public VolatileDemo() {
        f.add(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        JButton b = new JButton("Increment AutoCoinsLevel");
        b.addActionListener(ae -> {
            autoCoinsLevel++;
            System.out.println(
                    "ActionListener entered\nautoCoinsLevel = " + autoCoinsLevel);
        });
        add(b);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VolatileDemo().start();
    }
    public void start() {
        while (autoCoinsLevel < 10) {
            if (autoCoinsLevel % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println(
                        "autoCoinLevels = " + autoCoinsLevel);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done with while loop");
    }
}
```